# Is clicking on card for more information implied or should there be a button or text?

Tags: android, user-interface, cardview

I have an Android mobile application with summary information in a cardview. The card/itemView has an onClickListener that launches another activity with more detailed information. I'm trying to figure out if the touch for more information is implied or do I need to explicitly state "Details" or "More information" or "tap for details" or add a button or image instead of clicking on the card. Is there a way to present the card so it looks like it could be pressed? Just looking for thoughts or ideas, thanks.

Comment: Use a little icon.... `v` for example.. or `->`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if the `CardView` has some elevation so that it looks like a button, it is implied that a user can click on it.

You may also want to add some ripple effect in your card views.